# Sonatype Nexus User Role changes in log

Tags: nexus, sonatype

Hi I use sonatype nexus 2.14 and I want to see user roles changes in nexus logs.I found and added user request to logging but I still cant see user roles changes.
Is there any log appender for that in nexus 2.14

https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213464648-How-can-I-monitor-the-user-requesting-content-from-Nexus-

MyUser1-->added admin role-->see in nexus logs

Thanks